# Websocket connections in Apache server-status stuck "Sending reply"

Tags: javascript, apache, websocket

I've recently run into a problem where Apache is hitting a maximum number of child connections.

After reviewing mod_status' output, it looks like my WebSocket server I have created is an issue.

On the client side, I am simply connecting a websocket to a URL that is setup via ProxyPass in my configuration.

I do not know if the following is normal or not. Do I need to up my server resources? I do not believe a WebSocket connection should be in a constant state of "Sending reply."

Please note, the clients (the IPs) stay constant. As in, they do not change and they stay hanging.

[Here is my mod_status report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc8me.png)

**My question:** Is this normal behavior for WebSocket connections? I am expecting to handle around 500-1000 concurrent WebSocket connections. What should I do to produce a scalable solution?

What are my options? I was under the assumption that they are only TCP connections and do not take up a resource connection that is showing in mod_status.

**Important Note:** I have narrowed the issue down to the server responding to a request to open a new WebSocket - however the client that is receiving the response is not actively viewing the tab that made the request (as in, the tab connecting to the WebSocket in their browser has not been in focus for a while).